# benefits and impacts "in" or "on" the agriculture sector?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

Currently writing a paper but I keep asking myself if to use 'in the agriculture sector' or 'on the agriculture sector'. I googled this but both are used, not sure which is correct. But some websites and journals use 'agricultural sector' instead of 'agriculture sector'.

For example:

> The potential benefits and impacts in (or on) the agriculture sector
>   are.....

Answer (score 2):

The determining factor in the sentence is not the word *agriculture*, but the other words that take the prepositional phrase as a complement or adjunct. Different words license different prepositions. For instance, *impact*, either directly or in the phrasing *have an impact* takes [*on*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impact%20in%2Cimpact%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpact%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpact%20on%3B%2Cc0):

> conditions that impact **on** agriculture
>   conditions that have impacts **on** agriculture

*Invest*, on the other hand, takes *in*:

> The country invested **in** agriculture.

There doesn't have to be a single choice. *Comment* licenses both *about* and *on*:

> [Negative comment **about** race relations](https://books.google.com/books?id=LZUnCuYanNkC&pg=PA162&dq=%22comment%20about%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwxZ3D69vOAhVMKx4KHZdPC5IQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=%22comment%20about%22&f=false)
>   [A Comment **on** Heidegger's Comment **on** Nietzsche's Alleged Comment **on** Hegel's Comment **on** the Power of Negativity](https://books.google.com/books?id=aMaw7qyIa8IC&pg=PA255&dq=%22comment%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik8IqD7NvOAhUHmR4KHUDnCb44ZBDoAQgkMAI#v=onepage&q=%22comment%20on%22&f=false)